# Is it possible to find out which files are deleted during a filesystem recovery check?

Tags: filesystem, fsck

Some files/inodes are deleted during filesystem check if corrupted in a way after a system crash. fsck only reports "some inodes were deleted". Is it possible to know exactly what files were deleted and how to recover them?

Answer (score 5):

Check in your `/var/log/fsck/` directory the file `checkfs`. It is the logfile of fsck.

Comment: Unfortunately only inode numbers are logged, not for example previous filenames. So basically that is not helping at all.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/lostfound.html .

Answer (score 0):

It should also create a odd looking file name in the `lost+found` directory at the base of the filesystem that contained the deleted files.

You can look through those files and try to guess which was which, and possibly recover some information from them.